# How to treat base cases in Fibonacci proof by strong induction

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, induction

Let $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and $F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ for $n \geq 2$. Prove that $$F_0+F_1+\ldots+F_{n}=F_{n+2}-1.$$
I did two proofs by strong induction. The matter I want to discuss is whether the cases of $F_0$ and $F_1$ should be treated as base cases, or as separate cases in the inductive step (if that's required at all).

Let $P(n)$ denote ''$F_0+F_1+\ldots+F_{n}=F_{n+2}-1$''.

**Proof 1.**

*Basis.* For $n=0$ and $n=1$, we have $F_0=F_2-1=0$ and $F_0+F_1=F_3-1=1$, respectively. Thus, the base cases $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ hold.

*Step.* Fix $n \geq 1$. Suppose $P(k)$ holds for all $0 \leq k \leq n$. We prove $P(n+1)$, that is, $$F_0+F_1+\ldots+F_{n}+F_{n+1}=F_{n+3}-1.$$ Then
\begin{align*}
F_0+F_1+\ldots+F_{n}+F_{n+1} &= F_{n+2}-1+F_{n+1} \\ 
&= F_{n+3}-1.
\end{align*}

**Proof 2.**

Fix $n \geq 0$. Suppose $P(k)$ holds for all $k \leq n$. We prove $P(n+1)$, that is, $$F_0+F_1+\ldots+F_{n}+F_{n+1}=F_{n+3}-1.$$ Then
\begin{align*}
F_0+F_1+\ldots+F_{n}+F_{n+1} &= F_{n+2}-1+F_{n+1} \\ 
&= F_{n+3}-1.
\end{align*}

As you can see, the actual reasoning of the inductive step is not the problem. What bothers me is the treatment of the base case when doing strong induction. I've read in several places that proofs by strong induction **do not** require a base case. Instead, people often treat separate cases in the inductive step to fix an eventual gap.

Notice that the only (important) difference in the proofs above is the smallest value I'm fixing for $n$ and the range of values for $k$.

In **Proof 1**, since I'm fixing $n \geq 1$, the cases $F_0$ and $F_1$ have to be treated to ensure the validity of the argument when $n=1$. But then, couldn't these be done in the inductive step as a case for $n<2$ and the actual inductive step is done for $n \geq 2$? It seems to me that $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ don't perform the *logical role of a basis*.

As for **Proof 2**, since $n \geq 0$, am I not already assuming $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ in the induction hypothesis (since $k \leq n$)? In addition, when $k < 0$, doesn't $P(0)$ follow vacuously? Indeed, it seems redundant to prove $P(0)$ and $P(1)$. Nevertheless, that is still somewhat discomforting for me (as if something is missing). Thus, I'd like to be sure that **Proof 2** is a valid one.

What do you think? Are $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ *actual* base cases in **Proof 1**? Am I missing something in **Proof 2**? More generally, what are you thoughts on base cases in proofs by strong induction?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a source which claims that strong induction requires no base case?

Comment: To be clear:  you second proof is not complete.  All you have done is to prove the claim under some unsupported assumption.  You start by saying "Suppose $P(k)$ holds for all $k≤n$".  Well, what if it doesn't?  Now, it is a simple matter to confirm that $P(0)$ is true, but that step is necessary.  That is the base case.  Without that, your argument is incomplete.

Comment: @lulu Take a look at page 289 in http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf. It says "Note that no base case is necessary in a proof by strong induction. All that is needed is a modified form of the induction step in which we prove that if every natural number smaller than $n$ has the property $P$, then $n$ has the property $P$."

Comment: Well, that's nonsense.  I mean, perhaps there is some context omitted from that quote, but what is stated there is false or at least unclear.  In particular, I don't know what he means by "a modified form".  He could, of course, be embedding the base case into the statement in some way.  But you always need a base case.

Comment: For instance, suppose my claim was that "all natural numbers are $>100$".  Let $P(n)$ denote the sentence "all natural numbers $≤n$ are $>100$".  Then it is obvious that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$.  And yet, the desired claim is false.

Comment: @lulu Yes, good point. Indeed, I think he means embedding the base case into the inductive step. Somehow, it should be needed at some point when proving $P(n+1)$.

Comment: Ah, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546121/strong-induction-doesnt-require-a-base-case).  The claim is that, phrased correctly, the base case is vacuously true.  I would say, then, that you still have a base case.  The fact that it is easy doesn't mean that it does not exist.  But note that, in your case, you do not start with a vacuously true claim.

Comment: @lulu In addition, what do you think of the special case of $P(0)$ being true vacuously? Should that be treated explicitly?

Comment: Crossed comments.  Yes, it can happen that the "base case" is vacuously true.  But that is not the case for your argument.  You need $P(0)$ to be true, but that asserts that $F_0=F_2-1$.  That's true, of course, but it is not vacuously true.  It depends on the initial terms for the recursion.

Comment: @lulu Perfect, that was a subtle point I didn't get.

Comment: @lulu But then, fixing $n \geq 0$, I guess that only $F_0$ is sufficient as a base case, right?

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.  Assuming you mean $P(0)$ which, of course, also has information involving $F_1$.